# tensorflow - run inference(feed forwarding) twice on same image and model, ends up with different network output

Tags: tensorflow

something weird is happening to me. I run my feed-forwarding function in tensorflow twice loading the same model and on the same image, but I saw different network output.

here I build the graph

```
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[227,227,3])
output = train.forward(img, net)
```

and then I load in the model

```
sess = tf.Session()
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9999)
variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
saver.restore(sess, 'train/model.ckpt-20000')
```

and then I do the simple evaluation

```
imgdata = scipy.misc.imread(imagefile)
out_result = sess.run(output, feed_dict={image:imgdata})
```

I run above and each run I got different out_result value.

here is how I design the farward function (read in a list of network layers and construct graph in a loop)

```
# train.py

def forward(images, net):
    """
    network feed-forwarding
    Args:
        images: input batch of images
    Returns:
        feed-forward ouput before softmax activation
    """
    acts = []
    firstFC = True
    for layerIndex, layer in enumerate(net.layers):
        if isinstance(layer, ConvLayer):
            if len(acts) == 0:
                acts.append(convop(images, layer.nfilters, layer.filter_size, layer.stride_size,
                               layer.padding, layer.init, layer.activation, layerIndex))
            else:
                acts.append(convop(acts[-1], layer.nfilters, layer.filter_size, layer.stride_size,
                               layer.padding, layer.init, layer.activation, layerIndex))
        if isinstance(layer, PoolLayer):
            acts.append(maxpoolop(acts[-1], layer.pool_size,  layer.stride_size, layer.padding, layerIndex))
        if isinstance(layer, LRNLayer):
            acts.append(lrnop(acts[-1], layer.depth_radius, layer.bias, layer.alpha, layer.beta, layerIndex))
        if isinstance(layer, FCLayer):
            if firstFC:
                indim = np.prod(np.array(acts[-1].get_shape() [1:].as_list()))
                sample_size = acts[-1].get_shape().as_list()[0]
                reshape = tf.reshape(acts[-1], [sample_size, indim])
                acts.pop()
                acts.append(reshape)
                firstFC = False
            if layerIndex == len(net.layers) - 1:
                acts.append(fcop(acts[-1], layer.layer_size, layer.init,  layer.activation, layerIndex, isOut=True))
            else:
                acts.append(fcop(acts[-1], layer.layer_size, layer.init, layer.activation,
                        layerIndex, dropout=layer.dropout, wdecay=layer.l2_norm_wd))
    return acts[-1]

def convop(inpOp, num_outfmap, filter_size, stride_size, padType, init, act, layerIndex):
def lrnop(inpOp, depth_radius, bias, alpha, beta, layerIndex):
def fcop(inpOp, nOut, init, act, layerIndex, isOut=False, dropout=1.0,  wdecay=0.0):
def maxpoolop(inpOp, filter_size, stride_size, padType, layerIndex):
```

I am not sure what might goes wrong. any idea?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was certainly due to dropout being activated at inference. If it is useful for reducing overfitting while training, you have to deactivate dropout at inference to use the whole network. Otherwise a random subpart of your network will be activated leading to non-reproductible outputs.

Stumbled upon your question a bit late, sorry.